# XPath with SQL Server with no namespace

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery

I have a text field called image that holds XML.  A subset is below.  There is not a defined namespace so I am using a wildcard '*'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <delivery>
    <ticket>A430901474</ticket>
    <revision>00A</revision>
  </delivery>

  <tickets>
    <ticket>A430901474</ticket>
    <revision>00A</revision>

    <state>VA</state>
    <county>PRINCE WILLIAM</county>
    <lot>1</lot>
    <st_from_address>15414</st_from_address> 
  </tickets>
</NewDataSet>
```

The query below seems to be working but it is also returning the tags.  I only want the value of  attribute, if the tag is there.

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x =  (SELECT [image]
  FROM [QM].[dbo].[ticket]
  where ticket_id = 83831107)
SELECT @x.query('(/*:NewDataSet/*:tickets/*:lot)[1]')
```

Right now I get back:

```
**LotNo**
<lot>1</lot>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`query()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) returns xml... so, it's ill-suited to your task. Since you're only requesting a single value, you probably want to use [`value()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) instead ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23338)):

```
select @xml.value('(/*:NewDataSet/*:tickets/*:lot)[1]','int')
```

Assuming, for the sake of argument, that you could have multiple `lot` nodes in there, you could use the [`nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method like so ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23340)):

```
select 
 t.c.value('.', 'int') as Lot
from @xml.nodes('/*:NewDataSet/*:tickets/*:lot') as t(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `text()` node-test to get just the text values:

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x =  (SELECT [image]
  FROM [QM].[dbo].[ticket]
  where ticket_id = 83831107)
SELECT @x.query('(/*:NewDataSet/*:tickets/*:lot/text())[1]')
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  Both solutions worked.  @Cannon, I will only ever have one Lot value per ticket but I added that to my library since I will definitely have other situations where there is a node list.

Comment: Is there a way to test the Image text field, as to whether it is XML (or even make the @x think it is XML) and return no value?
Some of the tickets are parsed to XML where others are plain text.  The plain text will not have Lots.

Comment: @SpringerRider that should probably be another question.